# onSizeChanged() not called after layout width/height changed manually on Android 4.3.3 (ok on Android 5.0)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view

I'm coding a custom component, a `ViewGroup` that forces the size of a inner view:

```
myView.getLayoutParams().width = (int) itemSize;
myView.getLayoutParams().height = (int) itemSize;
myView.requestLayout();
```

but in the inner view the `onSizeChanged()` event is called only if the new size is smaller than the old one, if `itemSize` is bigger than the current size, `onSizeChanged()` is not called.

So strange...

**EDIT**

I change the width/height inside the `ViewGroup onLayout()`. Is it a correct way to change the inner views size?

**EDIT 2**

the problem arises only on my Asus tab (Android 4.2.2). On my nexus 5 phone (Android 5.0) everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `setLayoutParams`.

```
myView.getLayoutParams().width = (int) itemSize;
myView.getLayoutParams().height = (int) itemSize;
myView.setLayoutParams(myView.getLayoutParams());
```

Comment: @Adem, your solution have no effect.

Comment: @Rollno1 invalida() force a redraw, I need a ricalculation of the view size

Comment: @Seraphim's , do you want to recalculate children's sizes ?

Comment: Yes, I ricalculate the size of the childrens and a new size is assigned to the layout but nothing changes on the rendered view.

Comment: @Seraphim's, which layout do you use for myView ? setLayoutParams should work. you might give same size ? or your calculated children's size could be canceled because of using layout. for instance, if you use LinearLayout, the sizes of children will come back to previous step.

Comment: I found the problem arises only on my Asus tab (Android 4.2.2). On my nexus 5 phone (Android 5.0) everything works fine.